# Blocking URL's like /webmail & /phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

so I am running a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS & I am hosting my website on it. I was wondering how can I block URL's like /webmail/ or /phpmyadmin/ on my site? I am using apache2 & I don't really know how I could go about doing this. I tried looking everywhere but couldn't find a working solution.

What I would like to do is either block, or redirect the URL's. Either option would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution! I went to my apache2.conf and then added a RedirectMatch to the config.

For example I used this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/phpmyadmin$ http://example.com/404
```

To redirect my URL's to where ever I want!